# Calling a method in my Android Library with a return value in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, plugins

Good day! I have created a simple plugin for my unity app where I want to call the function in my Android Library with a return value. Here is my code snippet.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TestAndroidPlugin : MonoBehaviour {
    // Use this for initialization
    public Text mText;
    void Start () {
        Debug.Log("Androidtion is to be called");

        AndroidJavaObject jo = new AndroidJavaObject("java.lang.String");
        var ajc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.teameut.mylibrary.TestingMyWekaJar");

        mText.text = jo.CallStatic<string>("getMessage");
        Debug.Log("Androidtion is called");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

Here is my Library that I want to call.

```
package teameut.com.mylibrary;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import weka.classifiers.Classifier;

public class TestingMyWekaJar extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Helper.DoSthInAndroid();

        Log.i("Unity", getMessage());
    }

    public String getMessage(){
        String excption = "";
        try {
            Classifier cls = (Classifier)weka.core.SerializationHelper.read(getAssets().open("iris.model"));
            excption = "quite loaded";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            excption = e.toString();
        }
        return "Hello World " + excption;
    }
}
```

I am having a hard time calling the function with the return value. Please help!
Any help will be appreciated. :D

**EDITED**
Added the Logs

```
09-19 18:21:29.080: E/mono(22068): Unhandled Exception: 

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
09-19 18:21:29.080: E/mono(22068):   at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject.Dispose (Boolean disposing) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
09-19 18:21:29.080: E/mono(22068):   at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject.Finalize () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
09-19 18:21:29.081: E/mono(22068): Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
09-19 18:21:29.081: E/mono(22068):   at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject.Dispose (Boolean disposing) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
09-19 18:21:29.081: E/mono(22068):   at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject.Finalize () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
09-19 18:21:29.086: E/Unity(22068): AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.teameut.mylibrary.TestingMyWekaJar
09-19 18:21:29.086: E/Unity(22068): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.teameut.mylibrary.TestingMyWekaJar
09-19 18:21:29.086: E/Unity(22068):     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
09-19 18:21:29.086: E/Unity(22068):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:400)
09-19 18:21:29.086: E/Unity(22068):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:326)
09-19 18:21:29.086: E/Unity(22068):     at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
09-19 18:21:29.086: E/Unity(22068):     at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.c(Unknown Source)
09-19 18:21:29.086: E/Unity(22068):     at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$c$1.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
09-19 18:21:29.086: E/Unity(22068):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
09-19 18:21:29.086: E/Unity(22068):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:232)
09-19 18:21:29.086: E/Unity(22068):     at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$c.run(Unknown Source)
09-19 18:21:29.086: E/Unity(22068): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.teameut.mylibrary.TestingMyWekaJar" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.teameut.TestSampleTest-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.teameut.TestSampleTest-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.teameut.TestSampleTest-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
09-19 18:21:29.086: E/Unity(22068):     at dalvik.system.BaseD
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you attach some error logs so we can better understand what is going wrong?

Comment: @StevenCoull I have been trying to retrieve the logs in Unity. But cannot. I cnnot see the logs

Comment: @StevenCoull By any chance, do you know how to retrieve the String data in my getMessage() function using C#?

Comment: @StevenCoull found the error logs now :D

Comment: The error logs state that it can't find the library you're trying to call. You're trying to run this on an Android device, right? Have you included the Android Library in your plugins folder?

Comment: @StevenCoull I copied the  released .AAR file and pasted it in under Assets/Plugins/Android

Comment: Does your .aar file have the puzzle icon, and when selected show the 'Select platforms for plugin' menu as shown here? https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AndroidAARPlugins.html
If Unity hasn't imported the plugin properly it will show a plain white icon, and you won't be able to call the library from your app.

Comment: @StevenCoull yes it is in the form of a puzzle.

Comment: @StevenCoull Maybe because, I am extending the AppCompatActivity?

Comment: After a quick Google it does seem like AppCompatActivity can cause some problems. Perhaps you should take a step back and call a normal Activity that just returns 'Hello World' without any other code so we can confirm that is the source of the issue.